# Loop through textboxes and ruturn one of them

Tags: formula, formula-field, business-logic

I have three different text boxes(Email, Work Email, and Other Email) to enter email addresses. I created a custom field of type "Formula". I need it to loop through the three email(s) and return one email address, the first one it sees, and ignore the rest. I'm using IF statement but I don't seem to get it to work? Any help and suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: can you post your IF statement and logic on how the IF's should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BLANKVALUE(Field1, BLANKVALUE(Field2, Field3))
```

This is a bit easier to read than nested IF statements. BLANKVALUE takes two parameters, and returns the first (left) parameter if it's not blank, otherwise the second (right) parameter.

Comment: +1.  Much cleaner than my nested IF's. Wish I had thought of it  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you literally just want to return one of them, not really caring which one if more than one has data, then something like this will work

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Email__c)),
    Email__c,
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(Work_Email__c)),
        Work_Email__c,
        Other_Email__c
    )
)
```

If there's a value in the `Email__c` field, it uses that, regardless of whats in the other 2 fields.  If theres nothing in the `Email__c` field, it moves on to the `Work_Email__c` field, and if theres something in that, it uses it, regardless of whats in the `Other_Email__c` field.  If `Work_Email__c` is blank, it uses the `Other_Email__c` field, if it has a value.  If all 3 are blank it returns null.

Comment: There's really no need for the third IF, since if Other_Email__c were null, it'd be the same net result, but a larger total compiled size.

Comment: You are correct, updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've chosen an answer, but this might be a better way

```
 selectedEmail = email ? workEmail : otherEmail;
```

Which is the syntax for the **ternary** operator.
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeremy. I tried similar approach but return isn't supported by Salesforce.

Comment: Can you declare and assign variables? The return keyword is only included there because the question used the word "return", ...oh, and because I made a faulty assumption. I may be using SF soon, so I'm learning, starting today. Answer edited.

Comment: Can you have a buffer for loading a few things after you return from that method. Using email as ternary, there are lot of unfair load of primitive variables. Checking the value after the buffering and returning your ternary value would be better. I still don't think it's part of a salesforce issue though. Perhaps Scala or Haskell?